# Klaviyo custom template how to add css to only one part

Tags: html, css, html-email, email-templates, klaviyo

I am trying to build a custom template in Klaviyo (which is quite hard, they've made it almost impossible).

When I add CSS (by changing the view of a textblock to code and adding it) it applies it to all parts, you cannot differentiate well as you cant add custom classes.

In this example I want to add the dropshadow only to the white textbox but it adds it to all textboxes. Does anyone know a solution for this?

Best
Santi [image]

Comment: I'm not a Klaviyo user, but this article seems to suggest you can add your own draggable components, with a custom class? https://help.klaviyo.com/hc/en-us/articles/115005254188

Comment: Yes thats true but that is to make a template, you cant use those templates as universal content blocks unfortunately :(

Comment: Ok if we're restricted to what it produces, can you share the code from the td where you apply the box-shadow, and also the other td's that are affected? We *might* be able to get some CSS that would select one but not the other, although we have to watch what email clients can support (e.g. :nth-child doesn't have much support https://www.caniemail.com/features/css-pseudo-class-nth-child/)

Comment: I added it to this codepen (too long for a post): https://codepen.io/plant996/pen/MWxQPLZ. I had to copy it from inspector so it is also showing the things that make it a drag and drop editor which complicates things ..

Comment: Hmm I'm not sure there's a way to differentiate that via CSS sorry.

Comment: No worries I came to the same conclusion :) thanks for looking in to it!